# What is the correct approach to make "event animations" in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I am developing a small game using Flutter. I would like to add an animation that is a pointing finger floating to a button, and then by making it smaller and then larger, simulating a tap. Furthermore, I got the animation itself to work using `TweenSequence` based on https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/animations/staggered-animations.

What I don't understand is how to start and track the animation. Let's say I want to trigger it after the player progresses a level.
Possible approaches:

- Making a child widget responsible for "running the animation". Where to point the animations would be provided as parameters to the widget, and the state of the widget would override `widgetDidUpdate()`, discover that there's a new parameter, and then animate it. It would then need to notify the parent to "remove the parameter" using some callback. The parent will need to keep some kind of state variable to determine if it needs to show the animation.
- Create a child widget with a key, and use the key to call a `startAnimation()` method on the state of the child, with the parameters of where to point the animation. The parent in that case doesn't need to keep a special state for the animation itself, although it can.

There is probably a "right way to do this" that I didn't understand from reading the docs, I just don't know what it is.

Comment: I was using a Stack to achieve the animation on top of the other widgets, the question is more a about code organization and division of responsibility between objects.